# TFS 2010 Analysis Cube's "File" Dimension isn't Deleted on Rebuild

Tags: ssas

I have a problem with the Analysis cube - it keeps growing. I have managed to pinpoint it to a single dimension, the **Version Control File** dimension (id = file), which keeps growing. The problem’s symptoms are that with (almost) every rebuild, the old files (the .fact.map and the .fact.map.hdr files) do not get deleted. Over time this accumulates, and I’m reaching the point where the database reaches an unreasonable size of 146 GB, where the file dimension accounts for 145 GB of it!

My guess is that some error occurs, almost every rebuild which causes the operation to stop before it gets to its cleanup phase.

I know how to fix the symptoms, by deleting and manually recreating the analysis cube, but I need to understand why this happens and how to fix it once and for all.

Does anybody know how to explain / fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL Server do you have installed? I believe this may have been fixed in the latest CU for 2008 R2.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979778

Comment: Thanks - I will apply the fix this weekend, and hopefully my woes will be behind me!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I installed the 2008 R2 CU #2, as mentioned, and it didn't help - the files dimension **still** updates rather than performing a full refresh. I tried rebooting the DB server after the installation - nothing. Any further help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you force a rebuild, or just let it process itself? or you could try a recreate http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/how-to-recreate-the-data-warehosue-and-the-analysis-service-for-tfs/

Comment: I let it process itself. I will try to recreate as per the blog. Thanks!